# Is `BufferedInputStream.available()` safe to get bytes already received?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I want to receive some data from a `BufferedInputStream istream` wrapped around the stream from a `Socket`. The data first contains a byte `n` (8-bit unsigned integer) then `n` bytes which contains the actual message (in binary format, not string). So I wrote the following code (not tested):

```
public byte[] getNextMessageBytes() throws IOException {
    // Make sure the "length" byte is ready to be read
    if (this.istream.available() < 1) {
        return null;
    }

    // Peek 1 byte
    this.istream.mark(1);
    int length = this.istream.read();

    // -1 == EOF
    if (length < 0) {
        throw new EOFException();
    }

    // reset the marked byte
    this.istream.reset();

    // If all bytes available...
    // NOTE the 'length' byte is still in the stream
    if (this.istream.available() > length) {

        // Peek the bytes...
        this.istream.mark(length + 1);
        // Skips the 'length' byte
        this.istream.skip(1);

        byte[] data = new byte[length];
        int recv = this.istream.read(data, 0, length);
        if (recv == length) {
            this.istream.mark(0);
            return data;
        }
        // -1 == EOF
        if (recv < 0) {
            throw new EOFException();
        }
        this.istream.reset();
    }
    return null;
}
```

This code basically first read the length `n` byte. Then if `istream.available()` indicates the full length available, it will try to read the certain number of bytes and if successful, returns the byte array.

The [docs of `BufferedInputStream.available()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html#available%28%29):

> Returns an *estimate* of the number of bytes that can be read (or skipped over) from this input stream *without blocking* by the next invocation of a method for this input stream. The next invocation might be the same thread or another thread. A single read or skip of this many bytes will not block, but may read or skip fewer bytes.

Can "bytes that can be read without blocking" be interpreted as "bytes already received by the socket"? Will `istream.available()` actually return a **fewer** number than the data that is already received (i.e. some data not yet sent to buffer)?

Or will it actually be a better idea to start a thread that keep doing blocking read and push messages to a queue/list/vector/arraylist/whatever? (synchronization needed)

My application will need to be real-time (at best, but some delay in the order of milliseconds is basically acceptable as a recreational program), so I am quite worried about that. The program is mostly incomplete so I can't try yet.

Comment: I would consider NIO *with* an appropriate library wrapper (many choices from barebones to event dispatch queues).

Comment: In you find 1 ms acceptable I would make the code as simple as possible.  Personally I would have one thread per blocking connection, this should give you latencies of around 100 micro-seconds most of the time.

Comment: I can only warn and suggest to _not_ use `available`. It is not at all reliable. For instance: if you ever change your socket to a SSLSocket, it will always return 0 ... But if you have the expected length, you can always count the read bytes ... And I second Peter's suggestion to have one thread per connection.

Answer (score 0):

> Can "bytes that can be read without blocking" be interpreted as "bytes already received by the socket"?

Thats the *only* way it can be interpreted.

> Will istream.available() actually return a fewer number than the data that is already received (i.e. some data not yet sent to buffer)?

It can return anything from zero upwards even if is pending data. On SSLSockets it always returns zero.

However you don't need to call it, and you don't need all that elaborate code. Just read the stream, in blocking mode, and use multiple threads.

Comment: The first quoted statement: When I say that I actually assume, for example, it returns 1 *if and only if* 1 byte has already received by the socket (i.e. packet arrived the client side). Clearly it isn't the case according to the later part of your answer. After reading the comments I've already decided to run blocking operations on a thread instead.